# How to resolve CVS error: cannot rename file CVS/Entries.Extra.Backup to CVS/Entries.Extra: Bad address

Tags: windows-7, cvs

I've checked out a module from CVS onto a newly installed Windows 7 machine. The virus scanner has not yet been installed.

Later, when I try to do an update, I get the following error message:

**cannot rename file CVS/Entries.Extra.Backup to CVS/Entries.Extra: Bad address**

Has anyone seen and resolved this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be issue with VirtualStore - make sure you didn't checkout to Program Files or other protected areas.

And if you can - convert your repository with [cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/) - you'll save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I moved my source code from C:\Source to "My Documents" and have had a couple successful CVS updates since that point. I'll have to dig in a little further to better understand VirtualStore and its configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, had to exclude the library which I checked out to from the anti-virus monitoring.

Try to disable your anti-virus and checkout the code again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After disabling antivirus/malware protection tool, I was able to resolve the problem. Also, ensure that `cvsnt.exe` should be running in an elevated mode.